# Creating a task creator with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

Doing cs50w and I'm on the JS lecture. The assignment is to create a list of tasks, and everything in my code works, except that it doesn't append to the end of the `<ul>` and create a `<li>`. `document.querySelector('#button').disabled = true` still works, but the `append(li)` doesn't work.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

  document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = () => {
    if (document.querySelector('#task').value.length > 0) {
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
    }
  }


  document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function() {
    const task = document.querySelector('#task').value;
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = task;
    document.querySelector('#task').append(li);
    document.querySelector('#task').value = null;

    document.querySelector('#button').disabled = true;
    return false;

  }

});
```

```html
<h1>Tasks</h1>
<ul id="tasks"></ul>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Create a new task" id="task">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

I tried to fix the code with some friends and they didn't fix it, and I also compared the instructor's code and my own, so I am now asking the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Some selectors were wrong.

Try the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

  document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = () => {
    if (document.querySelector('#task').value.length > 0) {
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function (e) {
    const task = document.querySelector('#task').value;
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = task;
    document.querySelector('#tasks').append(li);
    document.querySelector('#task').value = null;

    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
    e.preventDefault()
    return false;

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has multiple typos, all with `document.querySelector()`. Throughout your code, you use the wrong selector. In my code below I have fixed all of these mistakes.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;

  document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = () => {
    if (document.querySelector('#task').value.length > 0) {
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function() {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#task').value;
    document.querySelector('#tasks').append(li);

    document.querySelector('#task').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>Tasks</h1>
<ul id="tasks"></ul>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Create a new task" id="task">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, I hope it is not too much trouble, but could you highlight which parts were wrong? Thank you.